# Move beans defined in applicationContext.xml to jboss configuration

Tags: java, spring, jboss

currently I have a spring project with an applicationContext.xml that defines some beans that are being used for code injection:

```
<bean class="com.example.Example1ClientImpl">
    <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" value="${EXAMPLE1_URL}" />
</bean>

<bean class="com.example.Example2ClientImpl">
    <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" value="${EXAMPLE2_URL}" />
</bean>
```

I want to refactor this code into another project that does not use spring. It runs on a JBoss server, so I assume these beans can be declared in `ejb-jar.xml` or `jboss-ejb3.xml`, but I can't figure out how.

Is it possible to do this and can somebody give me some pointers on how to do this?

EDIT: The ExampleXClientImpl classes are not defined in the project itself, they are defined in a dependency of the project. I could adapt this dependency, but I'd prefer if that's not necessary.

Answer (score 2):

If your aim is to make EJB's out of those beans then I would try doing a mix of xml and annotations:

**ejb-jar.xml**

Here you define your environment properties:

```
<ejb-jar xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" version="3.0" metadata-complete="false">
  <enterprise-beans>
    <session>
      <ejb-name>Configuration</ejb-name>
      <env-entry>
        <env-entry-name>EXAMPLE1_URL</env-entry-name>
        <env-entry-type>java.lang.String</env-entry-type>
        <env-entry-value>url1</env-entry-value>
      </env-entry>
      <env-entry>
        <env-entry-name>EXAMPLE2_URL</env-entry-name>
        <env-entry-type>java.lang.String</env-entry-type>
        <env-entry-value>url2</env-entry-value>
      </env-entry>
    </session>
  </enterprise-beans>
</ejb-jar>
```

**Ejb**

Here you create a `Singleton` (as this is the default Spring scope). IF you want to have the bean to have the default `prototype` scope of EJB's then you can annotate it with `Stateless` instead:

```
import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.ejb.Singleton;

@Singleton
public class Example1ClientImpl{

    @Resource(name = "EXAMPLE1_URL")
    private String url;

    ...

}

@Singleton
public class Example2ClientImpl{

    @Resource(name = "EXAMPLE2_URL")
    private String url;

    ...

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. It seems I didn't explain my problem properly, my bad. The ExampleXClientImpl classes are not defined in the project itself, they are defined in a dependency of the project. I could adapt this dependency, but I'd prefer if that's not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

I decided to use `@Produces`, I forgot that this existed. The solution looks something like this:

```
public class ClientProducer {
    private static final String CLIENT1_ENDPOINT_VAR = "CLIENT1_URL";
    private static final String CLIENT2_ENDPOINT_VAR = "CLIENT2_URL";

    @Produces
    public Example1Client produceExample1Client() {
        String uri = System.getProperty(CLIENT1_ENDPOINT_VAR);
        return new Example1ClientImpl(uri);
    }

    @Produces
    public Example2Client produceExample2Client() {
        String uri = System.getProperty(CLIENT2_ENDPOINT_VAR);
        return new Example2ClientImpl(uri);
    }
}
```

Comment: Good spot.. it basically is the equivalent of Spring's @Configuration

Comment: Thanks, I'm still pretty new to JEE and spring. It's not really helpful that the 2 are being mixed at my workplace :p And thanks again for your help.